# Navigate to URL in background.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm attempting to program a chrome extension which loads a website in the background page and checks it every so often to view changes. However, I'm having trouble actually navigating to a URL in the background page. I have looked at [this documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) but don't understand it. Any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Example:

### background.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Background Page</title>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script></head> 
    <body></body> 
 </html>
```

### background.js

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
```

### manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "page": "background.html"
  }
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "*://*/"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like how to actually view your background page? You can do that by opening up the extension tab in chrome, finding your extension, and clicking on "Inspect views: background page". That will open up a popup for `background.html` and from there you can view the background page, use the console to interact with your background script, read the log, etc.

Comment: Not exactly. I'm stuck with actually navigating to a site through background.html

Comment: Ok - what do you mean exactly by checking it to "view changes". Is there some API on the site that you want to load in the background page that you can interact with?

Comment: I mean that I'd like to check the site every 5 minutes or so to see if a certain element has changed. But I'm stuck on loading the site into the background page to start.